# How to Group By with data not exist SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group by all record with month in DateStart (yyyy-MM-dd) column and Count.
Conditions: Month from 1 to 3. If dont have data will show 0
**Table A**

| id | Name | DateStart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 2020-01-08 |
| 2 | ABD | 2020-01-08 |
| 3 | ABE | 2020-03-08 |
| 4 | ABF | 2020-04-08 |

I want result like this
**Result**

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

I tried

```
SELECT MONTH(DateStart) 'Month',COUNT(id)
FROM A
WHERE MONTH(DateStart) IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY MONTH(DateStart)
```

but it can not get Month 2

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: You need a table of months, then left-join this table to it and group up

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 have reached their end of life several years ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you can use a combination of a subquery and a LEFT JOIN with a derived table that contains all the months you want to include. Here's an example query that can give you the expected result:

```sql
SELECT months.month AS Month, COUNT(A.id) AS Count
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS month
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
) AS months
LEFT JOIN A ON months.month = MONTH(A.DateStart)
GROUP BY months.month
ORDER BY months.month;
```

In this query, we create a derived table called `months` using the subquery `(SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS months`. This derived table contains the months you want to include in the result.

Then, we perform a LEFT JOIN between the `months` derived table and the table `A`, using the condition `months.month = MONTH(A.DateStart)`. This will include all the months from the `months` derived table, even if there are no matching records in table `A`.

Finally, we group the results by `months.month` and use the `COUNT(A.id)` function to count the number of records for each month in table `A`.

The result will be:

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

This query ensures that all the desired months are included in the result, even if there are no corresponding records in the table.